# linux mkdir function can't authorize full permission

Tags: c, linux, permissions, mkdir

I am testing the `mkdir` function to create a new directory:

```
folder =  mkdir("./linux", 511);
```

or

```
 folder = mkdir("./linux", 0777);
```

or

```
folder = mkdir("./linux", S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO);
```

As you can see, I try to authorize the full permission to the directory but here's what comes up with `ls -l | grep linux`:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 manuzhang manuzhang 4096 2012-01-04 06:53 linux
```

why can't I authorize write permission for group and others?

**Updates**:
weird thing, as you guys told me I tried `umask`. It works with either `umask(S_IWGRP)` or `umask(S_IWOTH)` but **fails** with `umask(S_IWGRP | S_IWOTH)`, any ideas?

Comment: Without looking up `mkdir()`, the "511" looks odd to me, since it doesn't assign the same permissions to group and other as it does to user.  Also, you give two uses of `mkdir()`, and one test example, not attributed to either.  What version did you use before the `ls` test?

Comment: The man (2) page for mkdir says that the mode is as supplied, ANDed with 777, so that should work. Could you provide a few more details? What distro, and release of linux are you using? I'm hoping this is a fully standard glibc you're using as well?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you should use `mkdir("./linux", 0777)` rather than `mkdir("./linux", 511)`.

Comment: @tjarratt Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.13-0ubuntu13

Comment: @KeithThompson yeah, that's more intuitive

Answer (score 7):

From `man 2 mkdir`:

> The argument mode specifies the permissions to use. It is modified by the process's umask in the usual way: the permissions of the created directory are (mode & ~umask & 0777).

I suggest you look at your umask - it is probably set to `0022`. Try a `chmod` post-`mkdir`.

Comment: Can we get a code example? Does this mean I can call `mkdir("dir", unmask(0777))` in order to create a directory with full permissions? Or that it's impossible to create a directory with full permissions?

Answer (score 3):

Permissions set by system calls like `mkdir` and `open` are always masked against the current process's `umask`. You can change the current umask using the [`umask()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/umask) function; make sure to set it back when you're done.

Comment: I think doing a `chmod` after the `mkdir` is a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check the umask function: **man 2 umask**