# c++ creating directories with mkdir() and assigning their permissions

Tags: c++, chmod, mkdir

So I am trying to implement this linux command mkdir -m (permission mode) directory name. Like mkdir -m 444 a should create a folder name a with 444 permission.

What I tried to do was

```
for (int i = 3; i <argc; ++i) {
      mkdir(argv[i], *argv[2]); 
}
```

or

```
for (int i = 3; i <argc; ++i) {
      mkdir(argv[i], 0775); 
      chmod(argv[i], *argv[2]);
}
```

But instead it will make folders with different access such as 0064
Any help will be very appreciated

Comment: Hint: What type is `*argv[2]`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [linux mkdir function can't authorize full permission](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719867/linux-mkdir-function-cant-authorize-full-permission)

Comment: @aschepler char?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following question and see if it helps:

[linux mkdir function can't authorize full permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719867/linux-mkdir-function-cant-authorize-full-permission)

Bottom line?  Check `umask` in your shell, which is likely limiting your permissions.

Comment: Well i tried calling umask(0); it still doesn't work.

Comment: @jamesjung -  In the shell you are running your program from, when you execute `umask`, what does it display?

Comment: actually... I think using *argv[2] is wrong... So what i was trying to do was since when i run a file name mkdir.cpp I would do something like ./mkdir -m 0444 direcotryname, and since the file permission(digits) is stored in argv[2], I was trying to use *argv[2] as a permission and create directory like mkdir (argv[i], *argv[2]);

Comment: I would suggest running a very simple program, with one call to the `mkdir` function, along with hardcoded parameters.  See what happens when you try that, in order to isolate just the permissions issue you are trying to figure out.  Something like `mkdir ( "testfile", 0775 );`  See if the permissions work for that example, or if they are still incorrect.

Comment: Yeah I tried that and worked perfectly fine, however to create a directory with 0777, I would first had to set up umask(0); So I tried putting umask(0); before mkdir, but it still didn't work.

Comment: @jamesjung - You cannot call umask from the program and have it work, since the process itself already defines a more limiting umask for you (I suspect).  When you are not inside of your program, just at your shell prompt, what do you see when you run the `umask` command?

Comment: Oh Im sorry, i see 0022

Comment: @jamesjung - What I am trying to get to is this.  According to the page referenced above, your program's umask will be combined with the *process* umask that your program is already running with.  When all is said and done, you will probably need to change `umask` inside of your `.bash_profile` or other startup file to make this work.

Comment: @jamesjung - Ah, got it!  Can you edit `.bash_profile` or whatever your startup file is, and change that to 0777?  That should be the fix you need.